# How to render multiple Node js output in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an application that takes any video format and converts it into any desired format. I have built the back end using Node Js and Front End with React. The video converter in the backend returns the percentage of the value of the video converted so how do I display it in the front end.

I have tried res.write() returning multiple responses. But didn't work ... it didn't return any value it basically returned null.

So is there a way to solve this issue or should I just use ejs ????

This is how code looks likes

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
hbjs.spawn({input:////file path,output:///file path})
.on('progress', progress => {
res.write(progress.percentComplete)

})

res.end();

} )
```

Comment: You should send  `progress.percentComplete` to React, NOT just log it in Node

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: If you want to send info from server to client like what you have use socket.io. it's like how a chat app works. Since you have to show continuous progress thats the option.

Comment: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/14/socket-io-react-tutorial instead of chat you have to send the progress.

Comment: @ShahrzadGh This is how my current code looks like app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    hbjs.spawn({ input: 'Video_1_-_Factorials.mov', output: 'yo.mp4' })
    .on('error', err => {
      console.log('Not Working')
  })
        .on('progress', progress => {
      res.write(
          'Percent complete: %s, ETA: %s',
          progress.percentComplete,
          progress.eta
      )
        })

})

Comment: @SanishJoseph Thank you for responding. I am trying implement what you said

Comment: @MeherDeepak How do you get this information on the React? share code